# How to print symbol using variable with code of that symbol?

Tags: bash, printf

I need to output a symbol using variable that contains code of that symbol.

I already understood that in my code example bash thinks that i'm giving it a string. So according to specificator it outputs "4".

```
symbolValue=41
printf '%c' $symbolValue
```

I expect outputing of "A" symbol in fixed code. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try the following.

```
symbolValue=41
echo "$symbolValue" | xxd -p -r
# OR
xxd -p -r <<< "$symbolValue"
```

From [`man xxd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd):

> -p | -ps | -postscript | -plain
>
> output  in  postscript  continuous  hexdump style. Also known as
>   plain hexdump style.
>
> -r | -revert
>
> reverse operation: convert (or patch) hexdump into  binary.   If
>   not  writing  to stdout, xxd writes into its output file without
>   truncating it. Use the combination -r -p to read plain hexadecimal
>   dumps without line number information and without a particular
>   column layout. Additional  Whitespace  and  line-breaks  are
>   allowed anywhere.

Comment: It doesn't prints zero value of variable:( Actualy doesn't work with arguments like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 but works with 01, 02 , 03, ...